# VIM go back (CTRL-O) to already opened tab

Tags: vim

When I do `gf` then file under the cursor is opened in current tab. That's fine. When I do `CTRL-W gf` file under the cursor is opened in new tab - that's fine, but when I do `CTRL-O` newly opened tab is filled with the file that I have already open in my first tab resulting in editing the same file in multiple tabs.

Is there any way I can go back to the "first" tab using `CTRL-O`?

Answer (score 0):

When you follow [`:help CTRL-O`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#CTRL-O), you'll notice that the command is listed under *Jumps*; these *are within a single window*.

I fully agree with you that this is an inconsistency: Though there are commands (prefixed with `CTRL-W`) that open in a split window or new tab page (to let you keep the current context, which is helpful, especially as today screen real estate is much more abundant), you're leaving the "current window" navigation with this, and have to rely on window / tab management mappings (like `CTRL-W` `j`, `k` / `gt`).

Unfortunately, there's no "window movement history" command built-in like `CTRL-O` and `CTRL-I` do for (single-window) jumps. Such could be provided by a plugin, though; and this might already exist. For me personally, I can manage window and tab movements pretty well with some customized mappings, and don't miss a window movement history command. As I frequently move between windows and tabs, such history probably would become too cluttered to be useful, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I will just need to get used to it (that I can't do the way I prefer) ;)